# Puzzling error inserting data into HKWorkoutRouteBuilder in watchOS 4 Beta 4

Tags: healthkit, watchos-4

When I insert route data into HKWorkoutRouteBuilder I get the following error:

The connection to service named com.apple.healthd.server was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid

Here's a code snippet.

```
    workoutRouteBuilder.insertRouteData(filteredLocations) { (success, error) in
        if !success {
            print("inserting route data failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }
```

I patterned by impelementation from the Speed Sloth example.

Any insights would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
Here's some more info from the watch logs.  Looks like some sort of permission issue, but I haven't been able to track it down yet:

> fault 13:21:14.664262 -0400   healthd 
>   connection from pid 1705: Warning: Exception caught during invocation
>   of received message, dropping incoming message and invalidating the
>   connection. Exception: Invalid parameter not satisfying:
>   [authorizationStatuses count] == [typesIncludingParentTypes count]
>   Invalid parameter not satisfying: [authorizationStatuses count] ==
>   [typesIncludingParentTypes count] (   0   CoreFoundation
>   0x1dc04d25  + 153   1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x1d227181 objc_exception_throw + 39  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x1dc04be5  + 1     3   Foundation
>   0x1e43c1cd  + 93    4   HealthDaemon
>   0x2edf678f  + 2015  5   HealthDaemon
>   0x2ee6eed1  + 143   6   HealthDaemon
>   0x2ee6ec77  + 143   7   HealthDaemon
>   0x2ee7b99b  + 485   8   HealthDaemon
>   0x2f0e1e1f  + 143   9   Foundation
>   0x1e589393  + 19    10  Foundation
>   0x1e587<…>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to ensure that you request authorisation from the user for:

```
// Objective C
[HKSeriesType workoutRouteType]

// Swift
HKSeriesType.workoutRoute()
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick!  I can't believe I missed that.  Of course a more descriptive error message would be nice.

Comment: Agreed error should be improved. Also it seems like permissions overload to require this as a permission when the user has to grant location access for this to be useful anyway. PS feel free to make this as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: saved me! was missing HKSeriesType.workoutRoute() and took me a day to find that permission key - apple docs does not mention this

Answer (score 2):

> The connection to service named com.apple.healthd.server was
>   interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and
>   therefore this proxy has become invalid

Seeing this message indicates that the system process handling the request has crashed or exited. You should file a bug with Apple. Look for healthd crash logs and include them.

Comment: Is it possible to get crashlogs for `healthd` from the simulator? I can't find any reference to `healthd` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t forget to add request of WorkoutRoute for HKHealthStore at AppDelegate

Workout Route does not work with Simulator, and only works with some HKWorkoutActivityType like
 .walking, .running on OS4

```
private func requestAccessToHealthKit() {

    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

    let allTypes = Set([HKObjectType.workoutType(),
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
                        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!])
    if #available(watchOS 4.0, *) {
        allTypes.insert(HKSeriesType.workoutRoute())
    }
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: allTypes, read: allTypes) { (success, error) in
        if !success {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```